# CouchDB - .NET or Mono Equivalent Technology

Tags: .net, database, mono, mapreduce, document-based-database

Is there any active "document-based" database projects using .NET or Mono? Something similar to CouchDB, SimpleDB, LotusNotes, etc... Prefer open source.

I figure the JScript.NET technology could be used for the Map and Reduce functions over stored JSON documents.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at [nsimpledb](http://code.google.com/p/nsimpledb/). Also [RDDB](http://rddb.rubyforge.org/), [Apache Jackrabbit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Jackrabbit), [FeatherDB](http://fourspaces.com/blog/2008/4/11/FeatherDB_Java_JSON_Document_database) (a Java clone of CouchDB), [StrokeDB](http://strokedb.com/), [ThruDB](http://code.google.com/p/thrudb/), [DataWasp](http://www.datawasp.com/pages/index.html), and [M/DB](http://gradvs1.mgateway.com/main/index.html?path=mdb). Wikipedia lists all of the above as Document-oriented database technologies. Some are .NET, some aren't but I hope these links take you somewhere useful.

Answer (score 3):

I would like to add [RavenDB](http://ravendb.net/) to the list as well.  Written in C# and while it is not a direct clone of CouchDB, it was heavily influenced by the project.

One of the great features of the project is a service and embedded solution.  Meaning you can run it as a service on a server or you can run an embedded version within your application's process.

Right now, Windows is the only supported platform, but great strides have been made by [Rob Ashton](http://codeofrob.com/) and [Jérémie Laval](http://neteril.org/) in the past few weeks to get it to work under Mono and Linux.

Answer (score 1):

definitely look at  [NCouch](http://code.google.com/p/ncouch) also in this regard

Answer (score 1):

You might also want to check out [Divan](https://github.com/foretagsplatsen/Divan), a C# library for accessing CouchDB.